# How to know "RequireConfirmedEmail" is true or not in ASP.NET Core controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-identity

In `Account` controller I want to know `RequireConfirmedEmail` is true or not?

```
if (RequireConfirmedEmail == true &&
    !await _userManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user))
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "First activate your account");
    return View(model);
}
```

how can I know `RequireConfirmedEmail` is true or not in my controller ?

Comment: Either it's always required or it's never required. Which one it is depends on how it was configured at Startup

Comment: The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.signinoptions.requireconfirmedemail?view=aspnetcore-5.0) do say: "Gets or sets a flag indicating whether a confirmed email address is required to sign in. Defaults to false."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    ViewBag.RequireConfirmedAccount = userManager.Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount;
    ViewBag.RequireConfirmedEmail = userManager.Options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail;

    return View();
}
```

You need to check both settings in order to have the *real* situation.
If `RequiredConfirmedAccount` is *false* the other settings are totally useless.

Comment: You're my hero.